# Check if mouse pointer enteres panel components

Tags: vb.net

How do I check if my `mouse cursor enters any component in a panel` .

I stared  to write this code to check when the mouse enters any check box in my `panel` then I realised that I had no idea how to actually check if the mouse enters the components I the panel .

```
 Private Sub GenCheck()
    For Each CheckBox In datapanel1.Controls


    Next
End Sub
```

how do i go about doing this ?

*Edit*

I have an Idea but i'm not too sure about it

I could say

```
 Private Sub GenCheck()



       Dim cb As CheckBox
    For Each cb In datapanel1.Controls
        AddHandler cb.MouseEnter, AddressOf cb_MouseEnter
        AddHandler cb.MouseLeave, AddressOf cb_MouseLeave
    Next



End Sub
Private Sub cb_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub cb_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MouseHover` to determine when the cursor hovers above the `checkbox` like this.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.MouseHover        
    MsgBox("Mouse over!")
End Sub`
```

Edit:

I have put a panel on a form with two checkboxes to mimic your requirements, here is what you're looking for:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For Each pnlCheckBox As CheckBox In Panel1.Controls
        AddHandler pnlCheckBox.MouseHover, AddressOf Me.CheckBoxMouseOver
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBoxMouseOver()
    MsgBox("Mouse over!")
End Sub
```

Comment: There are also many other events to take advantage of for what you need to do, such as `MouseClick`, `MouseLeave`, and `MouseDown`.

Comment: thanks :)

I was editing my code so i didnt see this answer just yet , i remembered AddHandler so I guess this problem is solved

Comment: You were definitely on the right track, judging by what you put up there.

Comment: i will post the perfect answer in a minute

Answer (score 1):

**PERFECT WAY TO ACCOMPLISH THIS **

```
 Dim con As Control

    For Each con In datapanel1.Controls
        AddHandler con.MouseEnter, AddressOf con_MouseEnter
        AddHandler con.MouseLeave, AddressOf con_MouseLeave
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub con_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    'DO SOMETHING'
End Sub

Private Sub con_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   'DO SOMETHING'
End Sub
```